# Duvida em query no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

*Query* que eu estou utilizando

```
SELECT 
os_id,os_data,os_processo,os_solicitante,os_tipo,os_cliente,os_empresa,os_adverso,os_local,
os_comarca,os_advogado,os_preposto,os_documentos,os_status,login_nome,
sum(osh.os_honorarios_valor) as honorario,sum(osh.os_honorarios_os_despesas) as despesas from os so 
inner join os_honorarios osh on so.os_id = osh.os_honorarios_os_id inner join login lo on lo.login_id = so.os_advogado
where so.os_status !=0
```

**Tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE `os_honorarios` (
    `os_honorarios_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `os_honorarios_valor` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `os_honorarios_os_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `os_honorarios_os_despesas` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`os_honorarios_id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `os` (
    `os_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `os_data` DATE NOT NULL,
    `os_processo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_solicitante` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_tipo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_cliente` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_empresa` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_adverso` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_local` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_comarca` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_advogado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_preposto` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_documentos` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `os_status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`os_id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `login` (
    `login_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login_email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `login_password` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `login_rule` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `login_nome` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `login_cpf` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `login_status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9
;
```

**Teste que fiz:**

```
INSERT INTO os (os_id, os_data, os_processo, os_solicitante, os_tipo, os_cliente, os_empresa, os_adverso, os_local, os_comarca, os_advogado, os_preposto, os_documentos, os_status) VALUES (1, '2018-09-06', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', '8', 't', 't', 1), (2, '2018-09-06', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', '8', 't', 't', 1);
```

O que estou tentando fazer: Unir essas três tabelas e fazer a exibição .

```
<th>ID</th>
<th>Data</th>
<th>processo</th>
<th>solicitante</th>
<th>cliente</th>
<th>empresa</th>
<th>advogado</th>
<th>preposto</th>
<th>despesa</th>
<th>honorarios</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Detalhes</th>
<th>Dispesa</th>
<th>honorarios</th>
<th>Desativar</th>
```

O que está acontecendo é que quando executo essa *query*, no lugar de me retornar o esperado, me retorna vazio, já tentei usar `left join`, mas só me retornou um único registro.

> Obs.: No comando `inner join lo.login_id = so.os_advogado`, o campo *login_id* recebe o *ID* do usuário assim como no *os_advogado*

Comment: Ficaria mais claro se você colocasse um exemplo de dados do banco, a saída atual, e a saída desejada.

Comment: Veja bem, se você só tem registros na tabela de OS, INNER JOIN não ira funcionar, tem que fazer com LEFT JOIN

Comment: edita sua resposta lá que deu certo

Comment: @Sorack  era so editar sua resposta para eu marcar como a certa

Comment: @TulioVieira restaurei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas na sua `query`, os dois principais são os seguintes:

> O que está acontecendo é que quando executo essa query no lugar de me retornar o esperado me retorna vazio...

Pelo `INSERT` que você apresentou você tem apenas os registros da tabela `os`, portanto o `INNER JOIN` não apresentará resultado. Você pode ver na pergunta ["Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)
 o que isso realmente impacta, mas pelo que você apresentou será necessário utilizar um `LEFT JOIN`.

> ... ja tentei usar left join mas so me retornou um único registro.

Quando você utiliza uma função de agregação (no seu caso a função `SUM`) é necessário informar quais são os atributos agrupadores (`GROUP BY`), caso contrário, no caso do `MySQL`, sempre será mostrada apenas uma linha, somando TODOS os resultados. No seu caso tudo indica que você quer agrupar por ordem de serviço, portanto a `query` resultante seria similar ao seguinte:

```
SELECT os.os_id,
       os.os_data,
       os.os_processo,
       os.os_solicitante,
       os.os_tipo,
       os.os_cliente,
       os.os_empresa,
       os.os_adverso,
       os.os_local,
       os.os_comarca,
       os.os_advogado,
       os.os_preposto,
       os.os_documentos,
       os.os_status,
       lo.login_nome,
       SUM(osh.os_honorarios_valor) AS honorario,
       SUM(osh.os_honorarios_os_despesas) AS despesas
  FROM os os
       LEFT JOIN os_honorarios osh ON os.os_id = osh.os_honorarios_os_id
       LEFT JOIN login lo ON lo.login_id = os.os_advogado
 WHERE os.os_status !=0
 GROUP BY os.os_id
```

Comment: bom tipo agora não está retornando nada e tem dois registros no banco de dados da tabela @Sorack

Comment: Você pode passar o `INSERT` completo desses dois registros?

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta mesmo, de todas as tabelas

Comment: coloquei lá @Sorack

Comment: @Sorack, acredito que o `group by` não resolve o problema da pergunta, que é não trazer dados nenhum; acho que a outra resposta (erro no _on_ do _inner join_) faça mais sentido.

Comment: @rLinhares a parte do LEFT JOIN foi adicionada apos a minha resposta. O GROUP BY tem relação com apenas um registro, então ele tem que usar tanto o LEFT quando o GROUP.

Answer (score -2):

Não retorna nenhum resultado porque pelos exemplos das tabelas passadas, não vejo correlação entre os campos relacionados na seguinte porção da pesquisa:

> INNER JOIN login lo ON lo.login_id = os.os_advogado

Comment: lo.login_id é o id do usuario,os.os_advogado  tmb e o id do usuário

Comment: Então o que deve ser feito é uma conversão já que um campo é INT e outro um VARCHAR (o que pra mim tem um custo de processamento mto alto), então se for possível alterar o tipo do campo, e já criar ele como foreing_key da tabela de login.

Comment: falha minha kkk coloquei como inteiro

Comment: mas esse não é o problema kkk

Comment: ué, se o problema era que não retornava nada pra mim o problema é esse inner join que tava sendo feito de forma errada, assumo eu que todos os dados das três tabelas estão preenchidos corretamente.

Comment: o erro era uma serie de fatores inner join que deveria ser left join e estava faltando o  GROUP BY